# Why does npm isntallation of styled-components for React Native fail?

Tags: react-native, npm, styled-components

I am trying to install styled components for a React Native project:

`C:\Projects\Native1>npm install --save  styled-components`

The installation fails with following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Projects\Native1\node_modules\camelize
npm ERR! dest C:\Projects\Native1\node_modules\.camelize.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Projects\Native1\node_modules\camelize' -> 'C:\Projects\Native1\no
de_modules\.camelize.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The directory really doesn't exist in the node_modules folder. What can I do install the module succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean cache from your nodemodules folder

npm cache clean --force

**Or**

delete your nodemodules folder

then run

npm i styled-components

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, Docker's storage is full so I have to do a cleanup like so:

```bash
$ docker system prune -a
```